# Java threads: wait and notify methods

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have a thread that calls the `wait` method and can only be awoken when the `notify` method called from some other class:

```
 class ThreadA {
     public static void main(String [] args) {
         ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
         b.start();

         synchronized(b) {
             try {
                 System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                 b.wait();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
             System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
         }
     }
 }

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                total += i;
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code if the `synchronized` block in `main`, if the `ThreadA` does not execute first and instead the other synchronization block executing and completes to completion, then `ThreadA` executes its `synchronized` block and calls `wait`, what is going to happen and how it will be notified again?

Comment: @templatetypedef: thanks for reformatting (I just started to do this).

Comment: notify() is reserved for the Gods.  Mere mortals should use notifyAll().

Comment: @Julius Davies, ParkSuppot.park/unpark is closer to the gods, notify is still very noobish :)

Comment: @bestsss Explain yourself. Do you mean park/unpark is more efficient than wait/notify?

Comment: @Pacerier, sort of although it has been tweaked at a point and now it takes an extra memory fence. Park/Unpark requires no explicit sync (this is good, although it still may use native mutex) but proper use may require queues. For simple cases, park/unpark is usually superior to wait/notify but there is no notifyAll (see remark about queues). Also no need to wrap everything in try/catch(InterruptedException)

Answer (score 10):

If `ThreadB` gets through its `synchronized` block before `ThreadA` does, then `ThreadA` will block indefinitely on the call to `wait`.  It won't somehow be notified that the other thread has already completed.

The problem is that you're trying to use `wait` and `notify` in ways that they are not designed to be used.  Usually, `wait` and `notify` are used to have one thread wait until some condition is true, and then to have another thread signal that the condition may have become true.  For example, they're often used as follows:

```
/* Producer */
synchronized (obj) {
    /* Make resource available. */
    obj.notify();
}

/* Consumer */
synchronized (obj) {
    while (/* resource not available */)
        obj.wait();

    /* Consume the resource. */
}
```

The reason that the above code works is that it doesn't matter which thread runs first.  If the producer thread creates a resource and no one is `wait`ing on `obj`, then when the consumer runs it will enter the `while` loop, notice that the resource has been produced, and then skip the call to `wait`.  It can then consume the resource.  If, on the other hand, the consumer runs first, it will notice in the `while` loop that the resource is not yet available and will `wait` for some other object to notify it.  The other thread can then run, produce the resource, and `notify` the consumer thread that the resource is available.  Once the original thread is awoken, it will notice that the condition of the loop is no longer true and will consume the resource.

More generally, Java suggests that you always call `wait` in a loop because of *spurious notifications* in which a thread can wake up from a call to `wait` without ever being notified of anything.  Using the above pattern can prevent this.

In your particular instance, if you want to ensure that `ThreadB` has finished running before `ThreadA` executes, you may want to use `Thread.join()`, which explicitly blocks the calling thread until some other thread executes.  More generally, you may want to look into some of the other synchronization primitives provided by Java, as they often are much easier to use than `wait` and `notify`.

Comment: sir i had a doubt how to get to know which threads owns the lock on a particular object.can u clarify me please

Answer (score 1):

You could loop and wait until the total has been computed :

```
synchronized(b) {
   while (total == 0) {
       b.wait();
   }
}
```

You could also use a higher-level abstraction like a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: `new CountDownLatch(1)` is usually my favorite, condition to wait upon.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for ThreadB's run method to complete before you enter the synchronized block in ThreadA.main.  In that situation, since the notify call has happened before you started waiting, ThreadA will block forever on the wait call.

A simple workaround would be to grab the lock on b in main before you start the second thread to ensure the wait happens first.

```
ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
synchronized(b) {
    b.start();
    ...
    b.wait();
}
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion to ensure that ThreadB doesn't start working until A has the lock. However, you still want to have a loop inside the synchronized block to check that some success condition is true, instead of relying on the notify() call. This can be triggered by a spurious wakeup (http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA277&lpg=PA277&dq=josh+bloch+spurious+notify&source=bl&ots=yXLnOjw4Q4&sig=c8BR-aCh74RkGiP5pvysutl2I04&hl=en&ei=pflnTaXGDoH48AahhMmwCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a java.util.concurrent.Semaphore for this.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to add some flag that is used to communicate between the threads, so that B can signal to A when it is finished. A simple boolean variable is fine, as long as it is only read and written within the synchronized blocks.

```
synchronized(this) {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        total += i;
    }
    isDone = true;
    notify();
}
```

2) A needs to loop while waiting. So if your boolean variable was called isDone, and was set to true by threadB, then threadA should have some code like this:

```
synchronized(b) {
    System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
    while( ! isDone ) b.wait();
}
```

In this particular case, there's actually no reason to have the synchronized block in A - since threadB doesn't do anything after it finishes running, and A doesn't do anything except wait for B, threadA could simply call b.join() to block until it finishes. I assume that your actual use case is more complex than this.

Comment: the 2nd snippet must be     while(! **b** .isDone ) b.wait();

Comment: I don't think that it needs to be b.isDone. The boolean variable does not need to exist in the b thread, it is OK to have it in the parent class. Nor does it need to be marked as volatile, since all reads and writes to it happen in synchronized blocks with the same lock object. If I'm wrong about that, please let me know the details why. [I just re-read my post, and I think I see the confusion - I'm assuming that isDone is defined in the parent class, not in b]

Comment: the parent class is java.lang.Thread. Unless you are using some outer class where isDone is defined the code will not compile. Other than that as long as `b` instance and `isDone` are in bijection the code is ok (so the best place of isDone is in the class of b). No need for volatile if you to access them under the same lock.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I was assuming that ThreadB was an inner class of ThreadA, in which an instance variable in ThreadA would work, but re-reading the code, there's no indication that ThreadB is an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Why to make that complex ? Just use join() function of Thread.

```
ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
b.start();
b.join();
// now print b.total
```

Answer (score -1):

do not `synchronized(thread)`, don't do it, do not `synchronized(thread)`.. repat: no `synchronized(thread)` :)

And if you need to wait for the thread 'b' to finish, use b.join(), now your code is free to hang in b.wait()

--

Hopefully the source below can grant you an insight while sync(thread)/notify() I consider bad practice. (cut-cut)

Enjoy

---

**To proceeed below you make sure you have accepted Oracle's License aggreement, found there:**
https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewLicense-Start?LicenseUUID=7HeJ_hCwhb4AAAEtmC8ADqmR&ProductUUID=pGqJ_hCwj_AAAAEtB8oADqmS&cnum=&evsref=&sln=

Java sources (incl), called in init(), effectively called by any java c-tor, since java 1.5

```
private static **synchronized int** nextThreadNum() {
return threadInitNumber++;
}
```

//join (the method w/ nanos only increase millis by one, if nanos>500000, millis==0 and nanos>0

```
public final **synchronized** void join(long millis) 
throws InterruptedException {
long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
long now = 0;

if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
}

if (millis == 0) {
    while (isAlive()) {
    wait(0);
    }
} else {
    while (isAlive()) {
    long delay = millis - now;
    if (delay <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    wait(delay);
    now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
    }
}
}


public **synchronized** void start() {
    /**
 * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
 * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added 
 * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
 *
 * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
     */
    if (threadStatus != 0)
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
    group.add(this);
    start0();
    if (stopBeforeStart) {
    stop0(throwableFromStop);
}
}
```

//stop1 is called after stop ensures proper priviledges

```
private final **synchronized** void stop1(Throwable th) {
SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
if (security != null) {
    checkAccess();
    if ((this != Thread.currentThread()) ||
    (!(th instanceof ThreadDeath))) {
    security.checkPermission(SecurityConstants.STOP_THREAD_PERMISSION);
    }
}
    // A zero status value corresponds to "NEW"
if (threadStatus != 0) {
    resume(); // Wake up thread if it was suspended; no-op otherwise
    stop0(th);
} else {

        // Must do the null arg check that the VM would do with stop0
    if (th == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
    }

        // Remember this stop attempt for if/when start is used
    stopBeforeStart = true;
    throwableFromStop = th;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not provide any justification as to why you should not synchronize on the other thread object, nor does it answer the original question in any detail.

Comment: templatetypede, b/c join and join() and start() use sync. You don't want to mess w/ them (usually). And the answer is exact: use b.join()

Comment: if you use sync(thread)/notify() you mess up w/ any waiting join on that condition.

Comment: @bestsss- Can you point me to the part of the JLS that says that `join` synchronizes on the `Thread` object?  I've read over this pretty carefully and I don't remember ever seeing anything like that.

Comment: @templatetypedef start/stop/join all sync on the thread object. new thread syncs on the Thread.class. Look at the source, even it's not clearly stated, all the happens-before require sync on something to happen and since jdk 0.9 it was the thread object. De-facto it's a standard.

Comment: @templatetypedef, The advice is a very valid one, if people feel like skipping it, it's their own call.

Comment: @bestsss- Synchronizing on the `Thread` class object is not the same as synchronizing on individual `Thread` objects; the two are different entities.  Also, I pulled up the source for the `Thread` class, but the `start` and `join` methods are marked `native` and so I can't see the implementation.  I also can't seem to find something on Google that says that threads lock the `Thread.class` object, and the JLS special-cases `Thread.join` as a way of enforcing happens-before, so I'm not sure that synchronizing on the `Thread` class is the reason for happens-before.

Comment: @templatetypedef, dear goodness, do I look so stupid, that I need explanation that Class (object) is a different than an instance of a Thread. The point is only that such sync. exits even at far worse level. `syncrhonized(Thread.class){try{for(;;){Thread.sleep(0)}}catch(Throwable t){}}` halts any attempt to create a new thread on java 5/6. That was the only reason I added Thread.class. The source code about the affected method has been included in the answer and it's part of the java.lang.Thread class and ppl should not look at it unless they agree to Oracles license terms.

Comment: If used correctly (i.e. with an additional condition variable) there should be no problem with two different uses of the same wait/notify lock, apart from some performance losses. (And as said, `Tread.class` is a different object than `thread` here.)

Comment: @Paŭlo, the issue is that join uses  System.currentTimeMillis() which may change due to system time sync software or just user innervation. That can wreck Thread.join() if there is an external notify(), morealso any thread waiting on join() is free to consume that damn notify() call and your own thread held on wait() will do nothing but stay the OS scheduler queue.

Comment: This would be a bug in `Thread.join()`, I would say, since there always is the possibility of a spurious wakeup - and a "malicious notify" could be seen as that. And for consuming the `notify()` call by another wait, I would hope that the ending Thread uses `notifyAll()` and not `notify()`, as there may be more than one thread joining it, too.

Comment: @Paŭlo, take as you wish, as free advice, and a note that notifyAll in most cases is significantly more expensive call than notify(). Don't try to summon the bugs and such... hence the 1st sentence in my answer. Obviously I did know it and there was/is some reason for that. Thread.join is as bugged as any other code relying on System.currentTimeMillis(); here is a related bug caused by the same issue: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4290274

Comment: Maybe write it like this: *Because of a bug in timed join it is not advisable to use the Thread object as a lock object for other uses* instead of your categorical *do not `synchronized(thread)`, don't do it, do not `synchronized(thread)`.. repat: no `synchronized(thread)`*.

Comment: ...it's f-community wiki, feel free to edit, whatever you like. The issue is not only timed joins, the issue is not getting your own notify() the most if there is a 'concurrent' join(). Honestly how many of you knew anything about that stuff, it got yer attention.

Comment: @templatetypedef, *Thread.join as a way of enforcing happens-before, so I'm not sure that synchronizing on the Thread class is the reason for happens-before.* this is done via synchronized, the same is true for Thread.start(). Happens-before stuff requires memory ordering and the only way to be achieved on the hardware level are memory fences (or instructions that behave like fences, for instance CMPXCHG/CPUID on x86). Start/join are part of the spec. but sync(thread) is what implements the spec.