# How to fix Naked notify warning of FindBugs?

Tags: java, warnings, findbugs, notify

I have Naked notify warning of FindBugs. 
The below is my code.

```
synchronized (this) {
        this.notify();
    }
```

The "this" is "public class Controller extends Thread".
How to fix the warning?? I have no idea for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't it tell you what the warning actually is? (And have you considered implementing Runnable instead of extending Thread?)

Comment: Just don't use the thread to sync. on. more on using threads to sync on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121173/java-threads-wait-and-notify-methods/5121267#5121267

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The naked notify warning means that using the notify() method implies that there is some other thread waiting for some mutable state to change, and is waiting to be notified. But your synchronized block did not modify any mutable state, and so it seems odd that you would need the notify. If you modified the state of an object outside of the synchronized block, then it seems dubious that this code is thread safe, as there is another thread that is reading this data