# java and synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization

I am preparing for the SCJP exam and I am having trouble with fully understanding synchronization. At line 6, I have read that the thread running in main needs a lock on 'b'. Why does it need a lock on this object? My understanding is that a synchronized block of code is a protected area that only one thread can be in at any time? Moving on,the thread in main releases this lock and waits for the the thread in 'b to complete its run method. The thread in 'b' is then meant to notify the thread in main that it has completed. However, it does not look like it is notifying any specific thread here. This example is from the Sierra and Bates SCJP book. Any light that can be shed on this would be grately appreciated. thanks

```
class ThreadA {  
    public static void main(String [] args) {  
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();  
        b.start();  

        **synchronized(b) {  //line 6**
            try {  
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");  
                b.wait();  
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}  
                System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {     
    int total;  

    public void run() {  
        System.out.println("K");  
        synchronized(this) {  
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {  
                total += i;  
            }  
            notify();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: You are don't required a lock on that object. but synchronizing a thread is ok.

Comment: shouldn't b.start() be inside the synchronized section in main? As it is it could starve the main thread if it calls b.start() then the scheduler switches to the b thread and leaves the main thread before calling synchronized. then b.run gets the lock, then finishes and notifies. then main gets the lock and waits forever as notify has already been called.

Comment: sorry for the double comment, but stumbled upon another SO question with the exact same example that points out the issue I raised:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121173/java-threads-wait-and-notify-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At line 6, I have read that the thread running in main needs a lock on 'b'. Why does it need a lock on this object?

Because that is what that line does.  It acquires that resource. Other thread can get other synchronized block, but no other thread can acquire a lock on that object.

> it does not look like it is notifying any specific thread here.

This is true. The program has no idea which thread will be notify or even if any thread will be notified. You as the developer may conclude there is a particular thread which will be notified, perhaps because its the only thread wait()ing.

Answer (score 2):

Both threads synchronize on the same `Object` here, namely `b`. `main()` first aquires the lock, but then calls `b.wait()`, which releases the lock and waits for someone to call `notify()` on `b`.

That means that when the `run()` method, which in this case is called on `b`, calls `notify()`, this will wake up the `main()` method again.

So, that the lock is aquired on `b` isn't really important here, the important part is that both threads aquire the same lock, or the `wait()/notify()` cooperation won't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very corner case and you would **not** do that.
What happens is that `main` thread synchronizes on `ThreadB` object and `wait`.
When `ThreadB` finishes a `notify` is raised and as a result `main` is woken up and continues.
But this is not code you would normally write i.e. use `Thread` objects for `synchronization`.
To see how corner case this is, just remove the `notify` from the loop of `ThreadB`.
The code will still work due to the fact you synchronize on a `Thread` object and the implementation raises a notify after a `Thread` has finished.
The behavior is counter-intuitive and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

The code make use of `wait()` mechanism to ensure that `result` is computed by other `ThreadB`.

To wait on object you need to acquire lock on that object that is where `line 6`,`synchronized (b)` comes in to picture.

Better way to execute same program is using [Thread#join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) method.

```
public final void join()
            throws InterruptedException

Waits for this thread to die.
```