# Assuring wait() is called before notify() in threading, is it possible?

Tags: java, thread-safety, race-condition

I was looking at the Threading chapter in Kathy Sierra's book, when I encountered an example of using wait/notify methods :

```
 class ThreadA {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
 ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
 b.start();

 synchronized(b) {
 try {
    System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
    b.wait();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
 System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
 }
}
}

class ThreadB extends Thread { 
 int total;
 public void run() {
  synchronized(this) {
   for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
   total += i;
   }
  notify();
 }
}
}
```

Running the code always produces the same output:

> Waiting for b to complete... Total is: 4950

I modified the synchronized block of run() in ThreadB, by adding :

```
System.out.println("ThreadB is executed");
```

The question is: why do I keep getting

> "Waiting for b to complete..."

before

> "ThreadB is executed"

? Isn't there a possibility that thread b is executed before the main thread ?

Comment: That's the verbatim code from a book? It has a race condition...

Comment: This code is silly on so many levels, it's hard to know where to start. Is this really from a publish book? Mindblowing.

Comment: People need to learn how to program race hazards somehow. Otherwise how would other people spend hours of their lives debugging them?

Comment: There's no race condition---`b == this`. But it hardly saves the day.

Comment: @vanza - What's the race condition?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik indeed but that doesn't guarantee who will enter their sync block first.

Comment: @vanza the above code is copied exactly form the book without any altering.

Comment: Question about the same sample code: [java and synchronization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12543843/572834)

Comment: @TedHopp i don't agree. A race hazard is merely a situation where the outcome of the program is dependant on unpredictable events. In this case we cannot guarantee the order of execution, hence; race hazard.

Comment: If `b.start()` is called in `synchronized(b)` block, then there's no race condition.

Comment: @bmorris591 - Yeah, vanza's answer points out that the main thread will eventually hang if b's critical section is entered first. (Notice that I deleted my comment.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't there a possibility that thread b is executed before the main
>   thread ?

Yes, absolutely.

Usually `wait` is accompanied by some predicate to prevent this sort of problem.

For instance, ThreadB can have a variable which says it's finished.  In your case you can check to see if total is not 0.

```
synchronized (b) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
        while (b.total == 0) {
            b.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
}
```

This creates a happens-before relationship on the read of total with respect to the write in ThreadB.

Comment: The above code is a horrible example of threading. +1 for pointing that out.

Comment: @John Vint  is there any explanation how are these wait-accompanied-predicates implemented ?

Comment: @a.u.r A developer using `wait` ( or `await` counterpart) should implement it themselves.  The important take-away from my example is that `b.total` is written to while synchronizing on `b` as well as read under same synchronization.  The Javadoc explains in a similar way http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29

Comment: @a.u.r In my opinion, it is irresponsible for the book you read to not follow this concurrency idiom.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't there a possibility that thread b is executed before the main thread ?

Yes, such possibility exists, although it's very unlikely with a narrow race such as the one in this piece of code.

The code calls `b.start()` before acquiring b's monitor (the synchronized block). There's a chance that the main thread will be preempted during that window, and that thread B will run and acquire that monitor first.

In that situation, this program would hang, because the main thread would `wait()` forever since it missed the `notify()` from thread B.

Comment: +1 but note also that a dying thread calls `notifyAll` on itself---that's how `join` is implemented.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik interesting, didn't know that, but that still doesn't mean the main thread will be notified (B's `run()` may return and "death notify()" may be sent before A is waiting - which I agree is extremely unlikely, but still).

Comment: No contention to your main point (hence +1), but this is good to know:  StackOverflow has already seen a lot of questions where, referring to OP's code, the `notify` is entirely missing but the code still magically works.